# Not receiving mail from Heroku Sendgrid addon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sendgrid

So i've look at a few similar posts here on SO, but for some reason my sendgrid config in heroku is not working.

Here's my config / production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'poliking.herokuapp.com' }  
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:from => 'wesleycreations@gmail.com',
:user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
:password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
:domain => 'poliking.herokuapp.com',
:address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
:port => 587,
:authentication => :plain,
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Everything worked perfectly fine in development. I tried all the obvious, YES variables are properly set and YES I enabled my gmail to allow mail from less secure apps.

added gem sendgrid gem to my gem file

gemfile.rb

```
gem 'sendgrid-ruby'
```

Again, everything working fine in development and I am receiving email to same email address. But this isn't working in production. Any thoughts?

Here's the log:

```
...MailForm::Notifier#contact: processed outbound mail in 3.3ms...
Delivered mail 5f246d3cbf2d9_42af68b690f1c810d6@dad81cb4-1ce9-440e-b8...
```

Comment: Maybe setting `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` might help identifying the problem. What happens if you run your application in production environment in your computer?

Comment: For some reason when I make that option = true, the email doesn't even do its front end confirmation and I get:

Net::SMTPAuthenticationError:
535 Authentication failed: account disabled
(Most recent call first)

Comment: I tried Mailgun and had much better luck. Removed sendgrid addon, added mailgun, added mailgun-ruby to gem file, ran bundle install, and used this code and it works like a charm:

config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:user_name => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN'],
:password => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD'],
:domain => ENV['MAILGUN_DOMAIN'],
:address => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER'],
:port => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT'],
:authentication => :plain,
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}

Answer (score 0):

With `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false`, the errors raised during e-mail delivery will be suppressed.

Therefore, change that option to `true` so that you can diagnose the problem.